# PHP - Pull out array keys that have matching values?

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

Is there a way to look inside an array and pull out the keys that have keys with matching values? Questions like this have been asked, but I'm not finding anything conclusive.

So if my array looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 1
            [type] => 
            [message] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 2
            [type] => 
            [message] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 3
            [type] => 
            [message] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 2
            [type] => Limited
            [message] => 39
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 4
            [type] => Offline
            [message] => 41
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 5
            [type] => 
            [message] => 
)
```

And I want to get this

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 2
            [type] => 
            [message] => 
        )


    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 2
            [type] => Limited
            [message] => 39
        )
)
```

Comment: So basically what you want is to print only items that have the same `title` ?

Comment: Yes, this might be a super easy task, but my brain seems to be mush right now. I also need to keep the original keys in tact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$titlesCount = array_count_values(array_map(function($item){ return $item['title']; }, $input));
$output = array_filter($input, function($item) use(&$titlesCount){ return $titlesCount[$item['title']] > 1; });
```

where $input is the original array and $output is the result.

It counts each distinct value of title and returns only those that occur more than once.

Answer (score 0):

@Bugs's answer is better than this one, but I'm still posting it since I got the feeling that my solution will be easier to understand:

```
$arr = Array
(
    Array
        (
            "title" => "Title 1",
            "type" => NULL,
            "message" => NULL
        ),
    Array
        (
            "title" => "Title 2",
            "type" => NULL,
            "message" => NULL
        ),
    Array
        (
            "title" => "Title 3",
            "type" => NULL,
            "message" => NULL
        ),
    Array
        (
            "title" => "Title 2",
            "type" => "Limited",
            "message" => 39
        ),
    Array
        (
            "title" => "Title 4",
            "type" => "Offline",
            "message" => 41
        ),
    Array
        (
            "title" => "Title 5",
            "type" => NULL,
            "message" => NULL
        )
);

//create a "map" that will hold all the values of previous titles
$map = array();
$res = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $subarr) {
    foreach ($subarr as $subkey => $value) {           
        if($subkey === "title"){            
            if($map[$value]){ //if such a title already exists, add both of them to the result                
                $res[] = $arr[$map[$value]];
                $res[] = $arr[$key];
            }
            else { // add the current into the map                
                $map[$value] = $key;
            }
        }
    }
}
print_r($res);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 2
            [type] => 
            [message] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 2
            [type] => Limited
            [message] => 39
        )

)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($array as &$subarray) {
    if(is_array($subarray) && isset($subarray['title']) && $subarray['title'] == 'Title 2') {
        $matches[] = $subarray;
    }
}
```

Can be easily wrapped in a function taking subarray key and value as arguments.

Comment: You're not answering the question.

Comment: @alfasin Yes I am. Unless you want me to explain how `foreach` works.

Comment: As of my understanding, OP would like to search for duplicate titles in his array.

Comment: Title 2 was just an example. Title values are likely to change. So, this would need to be able to search dynamically for any matches on that key.

Comment: @MAZUMA Oh, I misunderstood you then. I though you needed a way to find all subarrays with a specific key matching an arbitary value.